# How can I convert an image to pdf in android?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I want to convert an image taken from my camera to a PDF so that I can programmatically read the text in it. I saw some links which suggested I use itext jars. I wanted to know the best approach for my requirement. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Use one of Rest online apis like http://www.convertapi.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image to PDF there are may libraries available like [iText](http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/), [droidtext](https://code.google.com/p/beratungs-app/source/browse/BeratungsKonfigurator/libs/droidText.0.2.jar?spec=svn36&r=36) so you can use it. But for your actual requirement is

```
so that I can programmatically read the text in it.
```

to read
text from your image file instead of converting it to PDF file, I suggests you to use OCR library for it. There are many **Android-OCR Libraries** ( [tesjeract](http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/), [mezzofanti](http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/) ) which are used for read text from image.